# Rotations in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have a general question related to rotations of wave functions. I have never really come across this in any of the core QM books, and was curious to know this.

Consider, then, a wave function that consists of an angular part and a spin part of a spin-1/2 particle given by, say: 
$$
|\psi \rangle = (z) ⊗ \begin{pmatrix}
1  \\
-i
\end{pmatrix} .
$$

What will happen if I rotate this state, say, around the y-axis by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians?

My approach is this, which I am sure is quite naive and possibly wrong. I will greatly appreciate any help.

My approach to this problem:

Write the angular part in terms of spherical harmonics (not caring too much about normalization for now):
$$
|\psi \rangle = | l = 1, m = 0 \rangle  ⊗ \begin{pmatrix}
1  \\
-i
\end{pmatrix}
.
$$

Now, when we rotate it, does the rotation matrix act independently on the angular part and the spin part? So, the angular states and spin states rotate like:
\begin{align}
$ R|\psi \rangle &= \sum_{m'}^{} d_{m'm}^{l} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \right) | l = 1, m' \rangle ⊗ d_{m'm}^{l} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \right) \begin{pmatrix}
1  \\
-i
\end{pmatrix}
\\
R|\psi \rangle & = \left( \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} |l = 1, m = 1 \rangle +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |l = 1, m = -1 \rangle \right)  ⊗ \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1  \\
-i
\end{pmatrix}
\\
R|\psi \rangle & = \left( \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} |l = 1, m = 1 \rangle +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |l = 1, m = -1 \rangle \right)  ⊗ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}
 1 - i \\
 1 - i 
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{align}
Hopefully the question is understood clearly. So, is this above calculation correct? Or is there something wrong with it.

Comment: “ Now, when we rotate it, does the rotation matrix act independently on the angular part and the spin part?“ Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly different take, if only in formalism. Several [Translation Operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_operator_(quantum_mechanics)) can be created as the complex exponential of the conjugate observable operator. For example, the complex exponential of the Hamiltonian divided by $i\hbar$ is the unitary time translation operator. In the case of rotations, construct the angular momentum operator with respect to the desired axis of rotation: [Rotations in Quantum Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_operator_(quantum_mechanics))

As I recall they go into this in some detail in Bransden and Joachain. Griffiths leaves it as an exercise.

$$\hat{D}(\hat{n},\phi)=\exp\left(-i\left(\phi\frac{\hat{n}\cdot\vec{J}}{\hbar}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

Just use the properties of the direct product. For *any* [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of two representation vectors, not just space and spin, $\Psi \otimes \psi$, so using capitals for the left space and lower case for the right,  you learned that the corresponding rotation generating operator acting on them is the [coproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_representation#Tensor_products_of_representations)
$$
\Delta (J) = J\otimes 1\!\! 1 + 1\!\!\! 1 \otimes j ,
$$
seen to satisfy the same Lie algebra as $J$ and $j$.

But the two terms commute with each other, so the full rotation trivially splits,
$$
e^{i\theta \Delta(J)}=\exp ({i\theta ( J\otimes 1\!\! 1 + 1\!\!\! 1 \otimes j) }) =e^{i\theta ~ J\otimes 1\!\! 1 } e^{i\theta ~ 1\!\!\! 1 \otimes j} = e^{i\theta ~ J }\otimes  e^{i\theta ~   j} , 
$$
so your reducible representation [transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Existence_results) as 
$$
( e^{i\theta ~ J }\otimes  e^{i\theta ~   j}) (\Psi \otimes \psi)=  (e^{i\theta ~ J } \Psi )\otimes (e^{i\theta ~   j}\psi).
$$
It's up to you to choose your angle to be a right one.

Comment: Thank you. This is amazing.